# how to understand flask session snippets if not session if session.modified:

Tags: python, session, flask, redis

when i read [Server-side Sessions with Redis](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/) or 
flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface sourcecode
I am a bit puzzled by this 'if' statement. **If the session is None then should the code attempt to get the session.sid on the following line or check the modified flag?**

```
def save_session(self, app, session, response):
    domain = self.get_cookie_domain(app)
    if not session:
        self.redis.delete(self.prefix + session.sid)
        if session.modified:
            response.delete_cookie(app.session_cookie_name,
                                   domain=domain)
        return
```

please tell me why,thinks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session` will be an instance of `RedisSession`, which is a subclass of `dict`. Checking the truth of a dict returns `False` if it is empty. When the session is empty, the Redis record and cookie are cleared.

You're confusing `if not session:` with `if session is None:`. Checking the truth of the session doesn't mean it's not set, it just means that it's falsey.